# Array of strings into array of objects

Tags: javascript

So I have an array of string like this in JS:

```
['07-01-16  06:55AM                   57 100313_1_1_065215.bad',
  '07-01-16  07:03AM                   57 100313_1_1_070315.bad',
  '07-01-16  07:26AM                   61 100313_1_1_072315.bad',
...]
```

and would like to become an array of objects so I can sort if by the two first fields like this:

```
{ date: '07-01-16',
  hour: '07:03AM'
  size: '67' 
 name: '100359_1_1_112700.bad'
}
{ name: '101105_1_1_200026.bad',
...}
```

Comment: so what is it that you have tried

Comment: Please go read [ask]. This site is not a code-writing service, you are supposed to show your own efforts to try and solve the problem. We can help if you have specific questions about /problems with code you have written.

Comment: I had a string and split it to get the array and then by space but didn't know how to assign the names to each field. Maybe I asked it wrongly? Sorry about that

Comment: @misorude Isn't it a bit too pedantic to harp on simple questions like these where the OP obviously doesn't know where to look? An appropriate answer fully in the spirit of SO might be something like "I suggest you check out Array.prototype.map", but since a lot of us already have working solutions for these simple things, why not just be helpful and share it? If anything, I'm sure there's a dupe for this question that we can close it with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use mapping and splitting with RegExp:

```js
const array = [
  '07-01-16  06:55AM                   57 100313_1_1_065215.bad',
  '07-01-16  07:03AM                   57 100313_1_1_070315.bad',
  '07-01-16  07:26AM                   61 100313_1_1_072315.bad'
];

const result = array.map((str) => {
  const [ date, hour, size, name ] = str.split(/\s+/);
  return { date, hour, size, name };
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100%}
```

Answer (score 0):

You try my code:

```js
const arr = [
  '07-01-16  06:55AM                   57 100313_1_1_065215.bad',
  '07-01-16  07:03AM                   57 100313_1_1_070315.bad',
  '07-01-16  07:26AM                   61 100313_1_1_072315.bad']

let result = arr.map(item =>{
  let values = item.replace(/  +/g, ' ').split(" ")

  return { date: values[0],
     hour: values[1],
     size: values[2], 
     name: values[3]
   }
})

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100%}
```